# Loading Jquery UI checkboxes without displaying normal checkboxes first

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jquery UI checkboxes to replace the standard html checkboxes. However when you enter the site first you will see the html checkboxes and then jquery UI will transform them. This looks really bad and I would like the person whom enters the site to immediately see the jquery ui checkboxes, without any flash of the html checkboxes.

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a slight change to the demo shown at http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox

```
$(function() {
    $( "#format" ).buttonset();
    $( "#format" ).show();
});

<div id="format" style="display:none;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" /><label for="check1">B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" /><label for="check2">I</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" /><label for="check3">U</label>
</div>
```

All I did was add `style="display:none;"` to the div.  So now the user will not see the html checkboxes.  Next step is to call `$( "#format" ).show();` *after* the jquery ui checkboxes have been created.  So the user will only see the ui checkboxes and never the html checkboxes.

Comment: but someone without javascript won't be able to use the form

Comment: d0h should have thought about that one, thanks! @bandi that is true but without javascript jquery UI wont work either.

Comment: @Mikhael of course it wouldn't work but with this approach your page won't work at all (invisible form elements).